# Determining which PHP source files are not used

Tags: php, code-cleanup

I have a large web app, and I think there are a bunch of old files that are no longer being used, is there an app which can tell me what these files are?

Comment: Can you explain the context a bit more please?  Are you talking about unused code? unused data and configuration files?

Comment: unused code files, this is a PHP project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also the [Dead Code Detector (DCD)](http://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpdcd). It finds functions that are never called, which may help to clean up even the files you keep in production.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to check out the project management tools available for php.

You can have a look at phpUnderControl (http://www.phpundercontrol.org/about.html) and CruiseControl (you can google it).

You can also use a tool (i.e and IDE) that will give a Code Coverage Report.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to start with your web server logs.  These will show you which files ARE being used.  From there you should be able to track down a good number of the files those reference.  Don't know of a good way to find out which aren't being used, only those that are.

Comment: This is what I was thinking, but I'd like to not have to write a program to parse over them.